# Retrieve data from a file using patterns and annotate it with its filename

Tags: bash

I have a file called `bin.001.fasta` looking like this:

```
>contig_655
GGCGGTTATTTAGTATCTGCCACTCAGCCTCGCTATTATGCGAAATTTGAGGGCAGGAGGAAACCATGAC
AGTAGTCAAGTGCGACAAGC
>contig_866
CCCAGACCTTTCAGTTGTTGGGTGGGGTGGGTGCTGACCGCTGGTGAGGGCTCGACGGCGCCCATCCTGG
CTAGTTGAAC
...
```

What I wanna do is to get a new file, where the 1st column is retrieved contig IDs and the 2nd column is the filename without `.fasta`:

```
contig_655    bin.001
contig_866    bin.001
```

Any ideas how to make it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'>' '
FNR==1{
  split(FILENAME,array,".")
  file=array[1]"."array[2]
}
/^>/{
  print $2,file
}
'  Input_file
```

OR more generic if your Input_file has more than 2 dots then run following.

```
awk -F'>' '
FNR==1{
  match(FILENAME,/.*\./)
  file=substr(FILENAME,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)
}
/^>/{
  print $2,file
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -F'>' '                   ##Starting awk program from here and setting field separator as > here for all lines.
FNR==1{                       ##Checking condition if this is first line then do following.
  split(FILENAME,array,".")   ##Splitting filename which is passed to this awk program into an array named array with delimiter .
  file=array[1]"."array[2]    ##Creating variable file whose value is 1st and 2nd element of array with DOT in between as per OP shown sample.
}
/^>/{                         ##Checking condition if a line starts with > then do following.
  print $2,file               ##Printing 2nd field and variable file value here.
}
' Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```